# How to add a column on fly ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am facing different kind of problem. In select query I want to add a temporary column on fly based on other columns value.

I have 2 columns

```
IsOpeningClosingDateToo (tinyint),
HearingDate Date
```

Now I want to check that if IsOpeningClosingDate = 1 then

```
Select HearingDate, HearingDate as 'OpeningDate'
```

If IsOpeningClosingDate= 2

```
Select HearingDate, HearingDate as 'ClosingDate'
```

I have tried to do this but failed:

```
SELECT 
      ,[HearingDate]
      ,CASE [IsOpeningClosingDate]
       when 1 then [HearingDate] as OpeningDate
       When 0 then [HearingDate] as ClosingDate
       end as 'test'
   ]
  FROM [LitMS_MCP].[dbo].[CaseHearings]
```

Comment: So you just want to change the alias of the column and not change the actual column selected?

Comment: Rather than change the columnname, use value as a single columnname , you know already what the values comes in that column. some thing you want other thing?

Comment: What if for first 3 rows `IsOpeningClosingDate` is 1 and for rest of the records its 0 then what should be your output ? because you talk about column "alias" which is the name of the entire column of the data. It is not possible to change on a "row by row" basis.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana that could be determined by IsOpeningClosingDateToo column, for each row it varies.

Comment: @Dane you got me sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest returning three columns.  Then you can fetch the values in on the application side:

```
SELECT HearingDate,
       (CASE WHEN IsOpeningClosingDate = 1 THEN HearingDate END) as OpeningDate,
       (CASE WHEN IsOpeningClosingDate = 0 THEN HearingDate END) as ClosingDate
 FROM [LitMS_MCP].[dbo].[CaseHearings];
```

Alternatively, you could just fetch `HearingDate` and `IsOpeningClosingDate` and do the comparison in Python.

The important point is that the columns in a SQL query are fixed by the `SELECT`.  You cannot vary the names or types of the columns conditionally within the query.